# How to apply an active style to menu using computed and props wit vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2

My menu is generated by a v-for, in data I have this array of objects where it sets all the attributes that I need to li and a href. Everytime i click in a menu the page reloads and I need to set the current menu of the page to active with some style. I tried v-bind but it seems to lose the style everytime the page reloads. So how can I do this with computed and props?

```
<template>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="link of links" :id="link.id" class="btn-menu"><a class="page-link" :href="link.to">{{ link.menu }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data(){
            return {
                links: [
                    {
                        id       : 1,
                        title    : 'Resumos',
                        to       : '/juridico/app/?pag=sys/casos/casos-resumos.php',
                        isActive : false,
                        location : 'first',
                        menu : 'Resumo'
                    },
                    {
                        id       : 2,
                        title    : 'Pesquisa',
                        to       : '/juridico/app/?pag=sys/casos/casos-pesquisa.php',
                        isActive : false,
                        location : 'first',
                        menu     : 'Pesquisa'
                    },
                    {   
                        id       : 3,
                        title    : 'Valores',
                        to       : '#',
                        isActive : false,
                        location : 'second',
                        menu     : 'Valores'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>

    .btn-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #0082c3;
    }

    .active{
        background-color: #0082c3;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: If the page does a reload you'll lose all of Vue runtime data, a computed or prop will not help you as it's part of the data that's gonna be regenerated on load. You could do a script that tests the address of the current page against your data links to find out dynamically which one is the current one.

Comment: If you end up using `vue-router` (which it doesn't seem is the case there, and there is no reason you should if your current solution suits you), you can use the class `.router-link-active` automatically set up for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a non-Vue solution to store which element was clicked last: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put a `mounted()` function in your .vue component (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and inside this function you can check where you are, change the property `isActive` inside the object (or add a new property to control that)  and add a class dynamically (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), something like this:

```
<li v-for="link of links" :id="link.id" class="btn-menu" v-bind:class="{ active: link.isActive }">
  <a class="page-link" :href="link.to">{{ link.menu }}</a>
</li>
```